Are the Russians planning a successor of the Soyuz?
The Soyuz has been flying since the 1960s and is somewhat outdated in this era. With many cheaper and reusable rockets entering the market, are there any plans to replace the Soyuz with an updated design?

Worth noting that the Soyuz has been massively altered over the years by successive waves of modernization; this (and the associated "modernized, modernized advanced, etc") seems to be a familiar thing in Russia.

I'm not sure if you are talking about the rocket of the spacecraft, but the answer to both is yes.
According to Wikipedia, for the spacecraft:

Russia plans to succeed Soyuz in the 2020s with the Federatsiya/Orel programme, using new reusable capsules launching on Angara rockets, to transport cosmonauts to orbit and to a space station around the Moon.

Also according to Wikipedia, for the rocket:

The Soyuz-7 (Russian: Союз-7) or Amur (Russian: Аму́р) is a partially-reusable, methane–fueled, orbital launch vehicle currently in the design concept stage of development by the Roscosmos State Corporation in Russia. The preliminary design process began in October 2020, with operational flights planned for no earlier than 2028. Amur is intended to substitute for the existing Soyuz-2 [rocket], at a much lower per launch cost.

